# Asterisk one way audio detection

Tags: asterisk

I have some calls have one way audio. I tried to write ${CHANNEL(rtpqos,audio,all) to CDR and think what if themssrc=0 than no audio, but it's not true. Is any way to detect one way audio?

```
ssrc=1149008855;themssrc=0;lp=1;rxjitter=0.000000;rxcount=0;txjitter=0.000000;txcount=194;rlp=0;rtt=0.000000 
ssrc=890247275;themssrc=956869399;lp=0;rxjitter=0.006240;rxcount=262;txjitter=0.000000;txcount=271;rlp=0;rtt=0.000000
```

Both of these calls have audio in both directions.